# function not working: not getting info from form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out why this code doesn't work. When I console.log the userinfo, it comes back as ["", ""]. So, it's not collecting the username or password.

According to the documentation,

```
GET /users
```

returns a list of users.

```
{"users": ["alex", "bill", "charlie"]}
```

- 200 - Successful

#### GET /users/:name

Display a user.

- 200 - Successful
- 404 - User not found

What's going on?

```
 /**
    * Click event handler for submit button, return username and password
    */

    function getInfo(){
            var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var username = user;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var password = pass;
            return [username, password];
    }

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", getInfo, false);

    var userinfo = getInfo();
    var username = userinfo[0];
    var password = userinfo[1];

    console.log(userinfo);

     /**
    * Get request for user's information, return user data, save as user.
    * Check for matching password - if true open userprofile.html
    * If false, show notice from index.html, reset user to empty
    */

    function showGetResult( username )
    {
            var result = {};
            var scriptUrl = "http://localhost:4567/main.rb";
            $.ajax({
                    url: scriptUrl,
                    type: 'get/users[username]',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                            result.append(data);
                    }
            });
            return result;
    }

    var user = showGetResult(username);
    console.log(user);

    function passwordCheck(user, password)
    {
            if (user[2] === password){
                    window.open = "http://localhost:4567/userprofile/userprofile.html";
            }
            else {
                    document.getElementById("notice").style.display = "block";
                    user = {};
            }
    }

    passwordCheck(user, password);
    console.log("still working");
```

Comment: Why not use all the jQuery functionality for this?  And your `type` value `get/users[username]` should be invalid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about using all the jquery functionality for this. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Oh, do you mean for the document.getelementbyid? I'll go jquery that up now.

Comment: `async: false` is 99.99999% bad [I would say 100%, but I leave little room for imagination ^^].

Answer (score 0):

When you’re dealing with the DOM it’s important to execute your code only after the page is fully loaded. If you don’t, there’s a good chance the DOM won’t be created by the time your code executes. That's why you keep getting empty results or sometimes error. To overcome this, you need to ensure your script executes only when the page load is completed.

```
window.onload = init;
var username = "", password = "";

function init() {
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", getInfo, false);
}

function getInfo(){
    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;
}
```

I noticed you invoke the function getInfo() manually in your code. I don't know why you are doing that. By using the above code, your function will be invoked only when the submit button is clicked.